# how save a table with help of inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

everyone! I would like to save the table after I used INNER JOIN.

```
CREATE TABLE result AS (
SELECT  measures.Day,
SELECT  measures.Day,
    stations.Name,
    measures.name_measure,
    measures_of_stations.Count, 
    measures.unit
FROM
    measures_of_stations
    INNER JOIN
    stations
        ON measures_of_stations.id_station = stations.id_station
    INNER JOIN 
    measures
        ON measures_of_stations.id_measure = measures.id_measure)
```

But I have an error "Invalid syntax next to ( ". Why? 
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `INTO` clause, see example below:

```
SELECT  measures.Day,
    stations.Name,
    measures.name_measure,
    measures_of_stations.Count, 
    measures.unit INTO result
FROM
    measures_of_stations
    INNER JOIN
    stations
        ON measures_of_stations.id_station = stations.id_station
    INNER JOIN 
    measures
        ON measures_of_stations.id_measure = measures.id_measure
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  measures.Day,
    stations.Name,
    measures.name_measure,
    measures_of_stations.Count, 
    measures.unit
INTO result
FROM
    measures_of_stations
    INNER JOIN
    stations
        ON measures_of_stations.id_station = stations.id_station
    INNER JOIN 
    measures
        ON measures_of_stations.id_measure = measures.id_measure
```